# How do I pass all arguments to function from smart contract`s ABI correctly?

Tags: python, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3py

I have following python code intended to *build, sign and send out* a transaction of tokens from my ETH wallet to smart-contract of **Polygon zkEVM Bridge**:

```
from web3 import Web3
from decimal import Decimal
import logging

ethereum_mainnet_RPC = config.infura_mainnet_address

polygon_zkEVM_RPC = "https://zkevm-rpc.com"
polygon_zkEVM_contract = "0x2a3DD3EB832aF982ec71669E178424b10Dca2EDe"
polygon_zkEVM_bridge_abi = [{"inputs":[],"name":"AlreadyClaimed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"AmountDoesNotMatchMsgValue","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DestinationNetworkInvalid","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"EtherTransferFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"GlobalExitRootInvalid","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidSmtProof","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MerkleTreeFull","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MessageFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MsgValueNotZero","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"NotValidAmount","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"NotValidOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"NotValidSignature","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"NotValidSpender","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"OnlyEmergencyState","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"OnlyNotEmergencyState","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"OnlyPolygonZkEVM","type":"error"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint8","name":"leafType","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint32","name":"originNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"originAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint32","name":"destinationNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"destinationAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"bytes","name":"metadata","type":"bytes"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint32","name":"depositCount","type":"uint32"}],"name":"BridgeEvent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint32","name":"index","type":"uint32"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint32","name":"originNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"originAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"destinationAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ClaimEvent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[],"name":"EmergencyStateActivated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[],"name":"EmergencyStateDeactivated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint8","name":"version","type":"uint8"}],"name":"Initialized","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint32","name":"originNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"originTokenAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"wrappedTokenAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"bytes","name":"metadata","type":"bytes"}],"name":"NewWrappedToken","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"activateEmergencyState","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"destinationNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"destinationAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"forceUpdateGlobalExitRoot","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"permitData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"bridgeAsset","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"destinationNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"destinationAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"forceUpdateGlobalExitRoot","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"metadata","type":"bytes"}],"name":"bridgeMessage","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32[32]","name":"smtProof","type":"bytes32[32]"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"index","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"mainnetExitRoot","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"rollupExitRoot","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"originNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"originTokenAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"destinationNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"destinationAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"metadata","type":"bytes"}],"name":"claimAsset","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32[32]","name":"smtProof","type":"bytes32[32]"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"index","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"mainnetExitRoot","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"rollupExitRoot","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"originNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"originAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"destinationNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"destinationAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"metadata","type":"bytes"}],"name":"claimMessage","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"claimedBitMap","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"deactivateEmergencyState","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"depositCount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getDepositRoot","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"leafType","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"originNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"originAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"destinationNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"destinationAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"metadataHash","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"getLeafValue","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"originNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"originTokenAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"getTokenWrappedAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"globalExitRootManager","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract IBasePolygonZkEVMGlobalExitRoot","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"_networkID","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"contract IBasePolygonZkEVMGlobalExitRoot","name":"_globalExitRootManager","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_polygonZkEVMaddress","type":"address"}],"name":"initialize","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"isClaimed","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"isEmergencyState","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"lastUpdatedDepositCount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"","type":"uint32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"networkID","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"","type":"uint32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"polygonZkEVMaddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"originNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"originTokenAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"name","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"symbol","type":"string"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"decimals","type":"uint8"}],"name":"precalculatedWrapperAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"tokenInfoToWrappedToken","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"updateGlobalExitRoot","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"leafHash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32[32]","name":"smtProof","type":"bytes32[32]"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"index","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"root","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"verifyMerkleProof","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"wrappedTokenToTokenInfo","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"originNetwork","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"originTokenAddress","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]

mnemonic = config.mnemonic

transfer_amount_percentage = 25

def float_to_uint256(value):
    decimal_value = Decimal(value)
    uint256_value = int(decimal_value * (10 ** 18))
    return uint256_value

def bridge_polygon_zkEVM(name, owner_id, mnemonic):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s", datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                        filename=f"wallet_{name}_{owner_id}.log")
    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ethereum_mainnet_RPC))
    web3.eth.account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()
    account = web3.eth.account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic)
    address = account.address
    balance_in_wei = web3.eth.get_balance(address)
    balance_in_eth = web3.from_wei(balance_in_wei, 'ether')
    transaction_amount = (balance_in_eth/100)*transfer_amount_percentage

    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(polygon_zkEVM_RPC))
    web3.eth.account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()
    account = web3.eth.account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic)
    private_key = account._private_key
    logging.info(f"connected to wallet {name} | address {address} | network {polygon_zkEVM_RPC} | owner_id "
                 f"{owner_id}")
    contract = web3.eth.contract(address=web3.to_checksum_address(polygon_zkEVM_contract), abi=polygon_zkEVM_bridge_abi)
    gas_price_gwei = 10
    transaction = {
        'to': polygon_zkEVM_contract,
        'gas': web3.eth.estimate_gas(
            {'to': polygon_zkEVM_contract, 'data':
                contract.functions.bridgeAsset(1, address, float_to_uint256(transaction_amount),
                                               "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", True, b"")}),
        'gasPrice': web3.to_wei(gas_price_gwei, 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(address),
        'from': address
    }
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key)
    transaction_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    transaction_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(transaction_hash)

bridge_polygon_zkEVM('main', 1234, mnemonic)
```

The code connects to my wallet in ethereum mainnet, gets balance of the wallet, then connects to Polygon zkEVM network and builds a transaction towards the smart contract of **Polygon zkEVM native bridge** (*https://etherscan.io/address/0x2a3DD3EB832aF982ec71669E178424b10Dca2EDe*).
Everything seems fine and correct function is found by the code in provided contract`s ABI, BUT an error arises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\api.py", line 77, in <module>
    bridge_polygon_zkEVM('main', 1234, mnemonic)
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\api.py", line 41, in bridge_polygon_zkEVM
    'gas': web3.eth.estimate_gas(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\eth\eth.py", line 293, in estimate_gas
    return self._estimate_gas(transaction, block_identifier)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 58, in caller
    (method_str, params), response_formatters = method.process_params(
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\method.py", line 233, in process_params
    _apply_request_formatters(params, self.request_formatters(method)),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\eth_utils\functional.py", line 45, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\method.py", line 55, in _apply_request_formatters
    formatted_params = pipe(params, request_formatters)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 666, in cytoolz.functoolz.pipe
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 641, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 504, in cytoolz.functoolz.Compose.__call__
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 253, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 249, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return ReturnType(result)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\eth_utils\applicators.py", line 22, in apply_formatter_at_index
    yield formatter(item)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 253, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 249, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\rpc_abi.py", line 233, in apply_abi_formatters_to_dict
    formatted_values = map_abi_data(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 253, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 249, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\abi.py", line 746, in map_abi_data
    return pipe(data, *pipeline)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 666, in cytoolz.functoolz.pipe
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 641, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 253, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 249, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\abi.py", line 781, in data_tree_map
    return recursive_map(map_to_typed_data, data_tree)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\decorators.py", line 30, in wrapped
    wrapped_val = to_wrap(*args)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 84, in recursive_map
    items_mapped = map_collection(recurse, data)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 68, in map_collection
    return datatype(map(func, collection))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 82, in recurse
    return recursive_map(func, item)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\decorators.py", line 30, in wrapped
    wrapped_val = to_wrap(*args)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 85, in recursive_map
    return func(items_mapped)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\abi.py", line 777, in map_to_typed_data
    return ABITypedData(func(*elements))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\normalizers.py", line 80, in wrapper
    modified = to_wrap(type_str, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\normalizers.py", line 135, in new_normalizer
    return old_normalizer(abi_type, type_str, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\normalizers.py", line 148, in abi_bytes_to_hex
    bytes_data = hexstr_if_str(to_bytes, data)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 253, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 249, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\encoding.py", line 178, in hexstr_if_str
    return to_type(primitive, hexstr=hexstr)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\eth_utils\conversions.py", line 106, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: expected a bool, int, byte or bytearray in first arg, or keyword of hexstr or text
```

It seems, something is wrong with arguments of bridgeAsset() function. Once again, what I am passing to this function and in the next line what data types are expected:

```
#what I am passing
bridgeAsset(1, address, float_to_uint256(transaction_amount),"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", True, b"")

#expected data types
bridgeAsset(uint32,address,uint256,address,bool,bytes)
```

**My question is how do I fix the error arising and why does it arise?**
Ask for any clarification you need in the comments.